# dynamically created menu dropdown not working

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu

I want to create a dropdown javascript menu dynamically in javascript.

I have created a javascript array of menu items in php from a mysql db and now I want to use a javascript function to create the menu on the fly when ever I want, so I can update items in the menu without having to use a server call.

the menu is built fine and loads but the dropdown will not work

this is my code

php code to create the array

```
   <script>
     var x=0;
     var outermenuarray=new Array();
    </script>
    <?
    $sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pages WHERE template_ref='15' ORDER BY menu_pos ASC");               
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql))
      {   
      ?>
      <script>
        var innermenuarray = new Array();
        innermenuarray[0]="<? echo $row['page_ref']; ?>";
        innermenuarray[1]="<? echo $row['menu_pos']; ?>";
        innermenuarray[2]="<? echo $row['sub_menu_pos']; ?>";
        innermenuarray[3]="<? echo $row['top_menu']; ?>";
        innermenuarray[4]="<? echo $row['link']; ?>";
        innermenuarray[5]="<? echo $row['indexpage']; ?>";                   

        outermenuarray[x]=innermenuarray;               
        x++;
      </script>
     <?
      }
     ?>
```

the css for the dropdown menu

```
    #jsddm{ 
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0
    }

    #jsddm li{
      float: left;
      list-style: none;
      font: 12px Tahoma, Arial
    }

    #jsddm li a{    
      display: block;
      background: #20548E;
      padding: 5px 12px;
      text-decoration: none;
      border-right: 1px solid white;
      width: 70px;
      color: #EAFFED;
      white-space: nowrap
    }

    #jsddm li a:hover{
      background: #1A4473
    }

    #jsddm li ul{   
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        position: absolute;
        visibility: hidden;
        border-top: 1px solid white
    }

    #jsddm li ul li{
      float: none;
      display: inline
    }

    #jsddm li ul li a{  
      width: auto;
      background: #9F1B1B
    }

    #jsddm li ul li a:hover{
      background: #7F1616
    }
```

the javascript for the menu

```
    var timeout    = 500;
    var closetimer = 0;
    var ddmenuitem = 0;

    function jsddm_open()
    {  jsddm_canceltimer();
       jsddm_close();
       ddmenuitem = $(this).find('ul').css('visibility', 'visible');}

    function jsddm_close()
    {  if(ddmenuitem) ddmenuitem.css('visibility', 'hidden');}

    function jsddm_timer()
    {  closetimer = window.setTimeout(jsddm_close, timeout);}

    function jsddm_canceltimer()
    {  if(closetimer)
       {  window.clearTimeout(closetimer);
          closetimer = null;}}

    $(document).ready(function()
    {  $('#jsddm > li').bind('mouseover', jsddm_open)
       $('#jsddm > li').bind('mouseout',  jsddm_timer)});

    document.onclick = jsddm_close;
```

and finally the loop to build the menu

```
    var innermenuhtml;
    function createtopmenu(){
    innermenuhtml='<ul id="jsddm">';
    var t=0;
    var s=0;
    for(var h = 0; h <outermenuarray.length; h++)
        {
            if(outermenuarray[h][2]=='0'){
                if(t>0){ 
                    innermenuhtml+='</li>';                         
                }
                t++;

                if(s>0){ 
                    innermenuhtml+='</ul>';             
                }
                s=0;
                innermenuhtml+='<li><a href="#">'+outermenuarray[h][4]+'</a>';
            }else{
                 if(s==0){ 
                    innermenuhtml+='<ul>';              
                    s++;
                }
                innermenuhtml+= '<li><a href="#">'+outermenuarray[h][4]+'</a></li>';
            }                  
        }

    innermenuhtml+='</ul>';

    }
```

I then call the funcion to create the menu and push into the div

```
    <div id="topmemnuitem"></div>
    <script>
    createtopmenu();
    $(document).ready(function() {
    var el = document.getElementById('topmemnuitem');
    el.innerHTML = innermenuhtml;
    });
    </script>
```

If I hard code the result of the loop into the menu, the dropdown works fine, but when I build it with the loop the dropdown doesnt work

does anyone have any clue why? I cant seem to see and reason why this will not work

Comment: Just going to throw this out there. Why not make life easy and just use a Bootstrap menu? http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/components.html#dropdowns

Comment: You are trying to create an HTML element with Javascript that uses PHP syntax. You can't use PHP syntax in the browser: your `echo` statements have to be executed on the server. You'll need to rethink this.

Comment: @MikeW You must not know what your talking about. You can use `<?php ?>` inside JavaScript strings as long as the javascript is on an .php page. His code is very inefficient though.

Comment: I dont understand what you mean about this, when I check the code in firebug the menu is built fine and loaded into the browser page.

Comment: Okay, so the menu is being built? But just the dropdown isn't happening?

Comment: @Shawn31313 Look more closely at the code. You'll see I'm right.

Comment: @Shawn31313 You must not know what you're talking about. The browser really can't execute PHP.

Comment: @JustinWarkentin The JavaScript isn't executing the PHP. Unless i'm missing something here.

Comment: @Shawn31313 Exactly! Hence MikeW is right about the problem.

Comment: javascript is not executing php. I run  php script to create a javscript array. the php is then forgotton about I then use the javascript array to build the menu. I can then alter the array and recall the build menu function and update the menu on the fly. this stops the need for any server calls. the menu is there on the screen but the dropdown element is not working

Comment: @JustinWarkentin You don't know what you talking about. Try this PHP script somewhere: `<?php
 $test = array("HI", "Hi");
 
 for ($i = 0; $i < count($test); $i++) {
?>
 <script>
  alert("<?php echo $test[$i]; ?>");
 </script>
<?php
 }
?>`

Comment: You can use stuff like: `<?php echo $test[$i]; ?>` inside your JavaScript as long as that JavaScript itself is inside PHP braces.

Comment: Your function `createtopmenu` is Javascript and tries to do this:`innermenuhtml+='<li><a href="dynamic_div<? echo $_SESSION['page'...`. This won't work unless you're emitting then entire javascript function from PHP while trying to inject data into the middle of it. At best this is just not good practice, at worst, it's impenetrable.

Comment: Just to clarify, PHP can be used to output any text, regardless of language (HTML, JavaScript, SVG, Whitespace, etc.).  Browsers will render `styles.php` or execute `client.php` as long as headers and outputted syntax are correct.  It was commonly used before preprocessors like LESS were created.

Comment: @MikeW That works. Because PHP is parsed before JavaScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed this using the help that @Mark Rijsmus posted. basically i just moved the

```
  var timeout    = 500;
var closetimer = 0;
var ddmenuitem = 0;

function jsddm_open()
{  jsddm_canceltimer();
   jsddm_close();
   ddmenuitem = $(this).find('ul').css('visibility', 'visible');}

function jsddm_close()
{  if(ddmenuitem) ddmenuitem.css('visibility', 'hidden');}

function jsddm_timer()
{  closetimer = window.setTimeout(jsddm_close, timeout);}

function jsddm_canceltimer()
{  if(closetimer)
   {  window.clearTimeout(closetimer);
      closetimer = null;}}

$(document).ready(function()
{  $('#jsddm > li').bind('mouseover', jsddm_open)
   $('#jsddm > li').bind('mouseout',  jsddm_timer)});

document.onclick = jsddm_close;
```

to inside the

```
<div id="topmemnuitem"></div>
<script>
createtopmenu();
$(document).ready(function() {
var el = document.getElementById('topmemnuitem');
el.innerHTML = innermenuhtml;
});
</script>
```

after the el.innerHTML = innermenuhtml; and it works fine

Answer (score 0):

When is the menu created? Is that before or after you call the binds?

Piece of jQuery documentation on .bind():
As of jQuery 1.7, the .on() method is the preferred method for attaching event handlers to a document. For earlier versions, the .bind() method is used for attaching an event handler directly to elements. Handlers are attached to the currently selected elements in the jQuery object, so those elements must exist at the point the call to .bind() occurs. For more flexible event binding, see the discussion of event delegation in .on() or .delegate().

=======

use:

```
$(document).on('mouseover', '#jsddm > li', jsddm_open);
$(document).on('mouseout', '#jsddm > li', jsddm_timer);
```

instead so each dynamicly created li within #jsddm will get binded.

=======

I'm glad i could help ;-)

Comment: I thought about that too.

Comment: I have changed the $('#jsddm > li').bind('mouseover', jsddm_open)
$('#jsddm > li').bind('mouseout',  jsddm_timer) to $(document).on('mouseover', '#jsddm > li', jsddm_open);
$(document).on('mouseout', '#jsddm > li', jsddm_timer); but still nothing

Comment: Ok i'm sorry to hear that.. This might be part of the solution. Besides your code look awfully bad.. you make use of all kind of global vars like the var 'innermenuhtml', that's some nasty sh** and can cause all sorts of problems.. Make funtions that return values instead. I know this won't help you directly, so it might be a good idea to make a jsfiddle example of the problem, and obviously replace the serverside code for hardcoded items.

Comment: @MarkRijsmus, thanks for your help, I am just simplifying it until it works then I will secure it up